# ghostscript converting text in pdf to graphics when converting to PCL

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, printer-control-language

I am using Ghostscript to convert a PDF to PCL.  I was expecting the resulting PCL to include commands to output the text elements, instead it is essentially converting the text in the PDF to bitmap data.  Is there any way to retain the textual data?

Comment: I think the way Ghostscript gets its device independence is by converting everything to a bitmap. Unlikely that there are any other options.

Comment: @Mark,  do you know of a library that COULD do it?

Comment: I'm sure there are libraries to extract the text from a PDF, but I don't know how much formatting they retain. I've never needed that function so I'm ignorant of the available libraries.

Comment: @Jeremy: please add the actual Ghostscript commandline (with **all** parameters) that you're using. Also tell the GS version. And if you can, post a link to the PDF you're trying to convert.

Comment: Do you just need the text from the PDF or do you need PCL with the text and layout?  There are a few libraries and even ps2txt that can pull the text data.  In order to deal with text in the PCL file it would have to do quite a bit of font conversion etc. which I'm guessing the GS guys are not interested in doing.

Comment: I need the text and the layout as well, otherwise the output isn't very meaningful or readable.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring the `pxcolor` and `pxmono` PCL XL (PCL6) devices.  These are high level vector devices but do not support text - well it will output bitmap characters in very restricted circumstances.

We don't really have plans to implement this.

The PCL model is Truetype and Bitmap centered whereas PDF and PostScript are more Type 1.  Also the encoding models (PCL vs. PDF/PS) are quite different.  This is not to say it is not possible, just a lot of work with little perceived benefit.

The PCL XL devices are important for printing - they allow sending vectors to printers (instead of rasterizing to PCL bitmaps like other device) which is important for performance.

We haven't seen much interest for these devices to be used on the desktop where text would be important.